# Data not being passed to view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass my data to my home.blade.php but I keep getting a error called "`Use of undefined constant data1 - assumed 'data1'`" I have double checked my code but still don't know what to do, my names seem to be able to be shown out in the view but not the hire status. Can someone help me thanks a lot

Home.blade.php

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th>     
        <th><strong><big>Hire Status: </big></strong></th>  
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
    <th> 
      @foreach(data1 as $value1)
      {{$value1->hire_status}}  
   </th>            
      </tr>
      @endforeach
         @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

HireController:

```
public function hire_view(){
    $data1['data1'] = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status',Yes)->get();

    if($data1 = "Yes"){
        return view('home')->with(compact('data1'));
    }else{
        return view('home')
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
    public function getData(){
        $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');

        if(count($data)>0){
        return view('home',$data);
    }else{
    return view('home');
}
```

Comment: Fix the test in you Hire Controller. if($data1 = "Yes"){. This should have == not =

Comment: I think the whole code is beyond any help :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your data in view file by two way like, 1st one is

```
$data1 = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status',Yes)->get();
return view('home',compact('data1'));
```

or,

```
$data1 = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status',Yes)->get();
return view('home')->with('data1',$data1);
```

and you have forgot the $ sign here,

```
@foreach(data1 as $value1) // "$" sign before data array variable.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is returning me undefined variable data1 error after putting the $ sign, but I know that by using compact it should be able to pass the data

Comment: Nope, it returned me this error now "Undefined variable: data1", it suppose to okay but don't know why it giving me this error

Comment: because of this i think `$data1['data1']` thats y i removed key in my answer,
you are accessing directly the array of values in your view thats why i removed.

Comment: I have tried both your method but the error still remains

Comment: From which controller are you loading your home.blade?\

Comment: I am using home controller for home.blade, wait am I suppose to put it in the same controller?

Comment: Then you have to send both array variable there, in home controller
return view('home',compact('data','data1'));

Comment: Actually I found out why, it was because of the name in my route, careless mistake..

Comment: But when I try to continue use your code I got this "Use of undefined constant Yes - assumed 'Yes'" what does this even mean?

Comment: :)...sometimes it happens with all of us. we have to find.

Comment: i think you are loading your view from home controller there you are passing only one array variable that is data but in view you are using data1 also so that it giving error.

Comment: So am I suppose to put them together in the same controller?

Comment: The only comment I can add here would be rather than using `DB::table` would be to utilise your model as that's what they're for.. Therefore, it would be `Hire::where('hire_status',Yes)->get();` providing your model is named Hire (of course)

Comment: yeah brother but both way result is same,we can use it as our requirement. but here you have to make hire model first,

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
@foreach(data1 as $value1)
```

in home.blade.php to

```
@foreach($data1 as $value1)
```

you simply forgot the $ there, so the code treats "data1" as a constant instead of a variable

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I missed that part, but now it is returning undefined variable data1 error, I thought by using compact this error should be fixed is it not?

Comment: I suggest closing this thread and  asking another question for that matter so more people can see the new problem:)

Answer (score 0):

In the 4th line of this piece of code

```
  if($data1 = "Yes"){
            return view('home')->with(compact('data1'));
  } else {
            return view('home')   
  }
```

if `data1` is not "Yes" you don't pass the data1 variable to the view, and then the view can not access it.

Oh my god, just realized you are using "=" in the comparison instead of "==".

Comment: erm.. isn't this a little similar to my question? Because I am facing some trouble where I am getting this error "Undefined variable: data1" now after putting the $ sign at data1 in foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data1 = "Yes"){
    return view('home',$data);
}else{
    return view('home')
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying but the error was actually the missing $ sign but after doing that I got an error "Undefined variable: data1", I had tried your method but still getting the error

Comment: i thinnk you miss 'Yes' in your logic ,first dd($data1['data1']) make sure this hold value   and try    $data1['data1'] = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status','Yes')->get(); problem may be in your if condition ..